# Extracting Information from client request

Tags: java, url, parameters, request, extract

How to extract url parameters in java.

Example request url: http://172.20.178.22:8080?deviceId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Server side i need to extract deviceId xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx as it is in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the `deviceId` param value in quotes, removes the quotes it doesn't work in url
Make your request URL as below:

request url: http://172.20.178.22:8080?deviceId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Use the below code.. should work for you

```
request.getParameter("deviceId")
```

Comment: Also it seems you are putting the deviceId param value in quotes, removes the quotes it doesnt work in url